# Mongoid's strange behaviour in production: it says it saved the record, but it did not appear in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoid

I have 3 models: Brand, Model and Equipment. Brand embeds Model, Model embeds Equipment. In development on OSX everithing works fine, but in production on EC2 Ubuntu 10.04 Equipment passes all the validations, says true on create and save methods, and even outputs "Equipment has been successfully created", but does not apper in db.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > b = Brand.create!(:title => "Volvo", :logo_file_name => "some_logo.png")
=> #<Brand _id: 4da29833b177070722000002, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4da29833b177070722000002'), title: "Volvo", logo_file_name: "some_logo.png", logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, active: true>
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > m = b.models.create!(:title => "740")
=> #<Model _id: 4da29893b177070722000004, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4da29893b177070722000004'), title: "740", active: true> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :024 > e = m.equipment.create!(:title => "1.6 Turbo", :start => 1987, :stop => 1993)
=> #<Equipment _id: 4da29a42b177070722000006, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4da29a42b177070722000006'), title: "1.6 Turbo", start: 1987, stop: 1993, acive: true, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :025 > bb = Brand.last
=> #<Brand _id: 4da29833b177070722000002, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4da29833b177070722000002'), title: "Volvo", logo_file_name: "some_logo.png", logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, active: true> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :026 > mm = bb.models.last
=> #<Model _id: 4da29893b177070722000004, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4da29893b177070722000004'), title: "740", active: true> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :027 > ee = mm.equipment.last
=> nil

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :032 > mm.equipment
=> [] 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :033 > e = m.equipment.new
=> #<Equipment _id: 4da29b15b177070722000008, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4da29b15b177070722000008'), title: nil, start: nil, stop: nil, acive: true, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :034 > e.title = "1.8 SLE"
=> "1.8 SLE" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :035 > e.start = 1988
=> 1988 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :036 > e.stop = 1994
=> 1994 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :037 > e.save!
=> true 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :038 > bb = Brand.last
=> #<Brand _id: 4da29833b177070722000002, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4da29833b177070722000002'), title: "Volvo", logo_file_name: "some_logo.png", logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, active: true> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :040 > mm = bb.models.last
=> #<Model _id: 4da29893b177070722000004, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4da29893b177070722000004'), title: "740", active: true> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :041 > ee = mm.equipment.last
=> nil
```

Why could this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True is returned when *validation is successful*, not necessarily persistence to mongodb.

Most drivers by default (not sure about Mongoid) write to mongo in a 'fire and forget' manner and don't wait to get a response from the server as to whether there was a problem saving the record or not.

You can turn on 'safe mode' by default at http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/configuration.html which will have the driver block until changes are persisted instead of 'firing and forgetting'.

Perhaps you are hitting an error on the server which you miss because the driver/mongoid is just not waiting for a response (unsafe write).

Comment: Well, in console everithing is still the same (creates and even tells that the title is taken if trying to create another one with the same title, though I still can't find it in db), but in web interface I get now new, very-very strange error: `Mongo::OperationFailure (: Modifier spec implies existence of an encapsulating object with a name that already represents a non-object, or is referenced in another $set clause):
  app/controllers/equipment_controller.rb:51:in `create'
`

Comment: I configured it. Somehow I've got old version of mongod -- 1.2.2, so I had to update to 1.8.1 and everything now works fine. Thank you!